# Jquery Clickable Div not working on inner div

Tags: jquery, clickable

I have this markup to make the entire div clickable.

```
<div class="myBox">
<div class="two">
    <h2> Title</h2>
    <p> This is the description</p>
    <a class="some-button-class" href="http://www.google.com/">check here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And this JS

```
 $(".myBox").click(function(){
 window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
 return false;
});
```

And this css

```
.myBox { cursor:pointer;width:200px;height:200px;}
h2 {font-size:28px;}
p { color:#fff }

.two { 
background: #999;
padding:50px;
}
```

But it's not working. Why?!

JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ryRnU/16/

Comment: If you want to use jQuery in your code on jsFiddle site, you need to choose it from options available in dropdown on left section "Frameworks & Extensions" - see corrected jsFiddle in my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change selector from '.mybox' to '.myBox'

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
 window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
 return false;
});
```

Updated your jsFiddle (corrected typo and added jQuery which was missing in your example) -> http://jsfiddle.net/ryRnU/17/

Comment: Yes - good catch of the typo - but this doesn't solve it - try yourself in the jsfiddle

Comment: well there was missing jQuery library in your example, see now updated jsFiddle in my answer

Comment: Thanks - any idea if it is possible to display the URL in the status bar on div hover?

Answer (score 2):

The class on your `<div>` element is `myBox` (with an uppercase B), but your selector is:

```
 $('.mybox')
```

with a lowercase B. Selectors are case-sensitive so it needs to be:

```
$('.myBox').click(function() {
    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: see above - didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but in addition to the other answers, you also didn't set a jQuery API to use with your fiddle.

Also, I like to place the jQuery code inside a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` function, to make sure the code is loaded as soon as the document is done loading.

This code should work on any website, with a jquery script imported to it.
http://jsfiddle.net/ryRnU/8/

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".myBox").bind('click', function(){
        console.log($(this));
         window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
         return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: No - this doesn't seem to work either http://jsfiddle.net/ryRnU/15/

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong, Use it like this :

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
 window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
 return false;
});
```

Comment: see above - didn't work

Comment: But its working fine, can you explain.